# Entity Framework 4 with Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4

I installed the ODP 11 lateset version, which suposed to wupport EF4.
But when i'm trying to add entity data model in the VS2010, I don't have the option to select Oracle Database.
Is there anything else i need to do?

Also, I have running on my pc Oracle Express 10g - Is the 11 ODP will work with this DB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something, but EF4 is still not supported in the latest ODP.NET